# return time_t error

Tags: c

The program will return a set of string "This is James: 00:00:00" and a time format but it crashed. I believe there is a missing memory allocation but couldn't pin where the error is.

```
FREObject result = 0;

uint32_t len = -1;
const uint8_t *str = 0;
char *temp;
uint8_t *strAll;

time_t curtime;
struct tm *loctime;

/* Get the current time. */
curtime = time(NULL);

/* Convert it to local time representation. */
loctime = localtime(&curtime);

//Turn our actionscrpt code into native code.
if(FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str) == FRE_OK) {
    temp = "Hello World! This is ";

    strAll = (char *)malloc(sizeof(temp) + sizeof(str) + sizeof(loctime));
    strcpy(strAll,temp);
    strcat(strAll,str);
    strcat(strAll,asctime(loctime));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `strlen` instead of `sizeof` here:

```
strAll = (char *)malloc(sizeof(temp) + sizeof(str) + sizeof(loctime));
```

Also the **`sizeof(loctime)` makes very little sense**. You probably want to replace it with the length of `asctime(loctime)`.

Maybe something like this:

```
char *asc = asctime(loctime);
strAll = malloc(strlen(temp) + strlen(str) + stren(asc) + 1);
```

Comment: that works although I wonder why all the code are using "sizeof" instead? Does it mean it should only be used for multiply datatype as in: sizeof(char) * strlen(str)

Comment: @JamesONG The `sizeof` operator works differently than you think. I can't provide an adequate explanation in 600 characters, you need to read a book.

Comment: ok will read up. I will also need to output time in milliseconds format instead of date structure. I have been looking up many types of time, which time function do you suggest is best for Windows 7 OS with GCC compilers? I'm need to track MIDI timing, therefore, will need to compare milliseconds for scoring parts.

Comment: @JamesONG Try one of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725473) maybe ?